# Need to make changes to the "SAML2Utils.class" of openfedlib.jar

Tags: java, jar, single-sign-on

I am looking to debug something and need to make changes to the `SAML2Utils.class` of `openfedlib.jar`

Does anyone have the source code for `openfedlib.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the source for SAML2Utils: http://sources.forgerock.org/browse/~br=trunk/openam/trunk/openam/openam-federation/openam-federation-library/src/main/java/com/sun/identity/saml2/common/SAML2Utils.java?r=9562

You can also find the other classes in that repository if you need them.